# Check JavaScript for Unexpected Assignments

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have some JavaScript that I want to check to make sure I have no occurrences of using the assignment operator (=) as opposed to the equality operator (==). I've looked at JShint, JSLint, and the Google Closure Compiler. Unfortunately, no matter how I set the previous two tools, I get mounds of junk "errors" about all kinds of nit-picky little things, and the Google Closure Compiler does not detect this very common error.

Are there any tools I may use as an alternative to the three above? Really, I just want to check for this one error. I don't care about anything else.

Comment: The only other option ignoring the ones you've mentioned would be to use some form of regexp to look for it, good luck though. I would just use jshint or jslint and fix the rest of the "junk errors" while you're there.

Comment: You could also use your favorite editor to search for `=` and look at each occurrence manually.

Comment: Eek... I was hoping to avoid that... the project has over 12,000 lines.

Comment: Ouch. bet ya wish the project started out using jslint or similar from the beginning.

Comment: Best bet would be to use jslint or jshint and turn off as many of the optional checks as possible to reduce the amount of errors it catches

Comment: http://jshint.com/, http://eslint.org/ ... configure the tools you use.

Comment: Yeah, 12k lines sounds like a lot, but it's often only hours, not days-on-days. Bite the bullet (and lint it up). ;^)

Comment: `(?<!=)=(?!=)` and a text editor to find all occurrences of single `=`!   :)

Comment: In retrospect, I have now started using JsLint throughout my development process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [grasp](http://www.graspjs.com/), it is similar to grep, but it searches Javascript abstract syntax trees.

For example, if you checkout the [keybase node-client](https://github.com/keybase/node-client), and then run:

```
 grasp -r 'if.test[op==]'
```

It will match all the lines in `.js` files that contain if-statements that have assignment int their test, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a quick example call for this issue?

Comment: @ruffin, I am not entirely sure what you mean. I just want a tool that can scour all the lines of code I have to detect something like this: 
  function test(x){
   if(x=10){
    //do something
   }
  }

Comment: @Tobi Thanks! I am definitely going to install that tool for use in the future. In the meantime, I ran all the code through various formatting applications so that the code style became uniform and I could search using a simple regular expression. In my case, I used UltraEdit to do so. Given there doesn't appear to be a tool that does exactly what I need, I think I just might make an open source program based on JSLint that looks for specific errors. I think that could help a lot of people.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann This: `grasp -r 'if.test[right.value=0]' app/assets/javascripts ` will match all if statements with the right value as 0. I can come up with an example for assignment.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann Was a question for Tobi. Was trying to grok `grasp` usage, which he provided -- just looking for one that'd answer your question exactly. That's an interesting, and useful, tool. Edit: Ah, his latest edit is money. Sorry I can't upvote twice. That's neat.

Comment: @ruffin It is, it takes a little trial and error, but it's worth it, since it searches at a deeper level than just regexes.